# How to compare list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Been trying to wrap my head around comparing a list of lists of dictionaries  against other dictionaries in the same list of lists in Python 3.7.1 (sorry if this is unclear...I'll try to spell it out with code).

I'm essentially trying to write some python that would compare what's installed on a dynamic number of servers which will be provided by the user. A simplified dataset essentially looks like this:

```
[
  [
   {'server':'serverA', 'software':'hadoop','version':'1.0'},
   {'server':'serverA', 'software':'python','version':'3.6'},
   {'server':'serverA', 'software':'pip','version':'18.0'}
  ],
  [
   {'server':'serverB', 'software':'python','version':'3.5'},
   {'server':'serverB', 'software':'pip', 'version': '18.0'}
  ],
  [
   {'server':'testServerA', 'software':'hadoop','version':'1.0'},
   {'server':'testServerA', 'software':'pip', 'version':'18.0'}
  ],
  [
   {'server':'testServerB', 'software':'hadoop','version':'1.0'},
   {'server':'testServerB', 'software':'python','version':'3.6'},
   {'server':'testServerB', 'software':'pip','version':'18.0'},
   {'server':'testServerB', 'software':'ruby','version':'2.5'}
  ]
]
```

I essentially am trying to determine which servers have the software installed that others do not or are on different versions from another one. The goal is to easily identify what needs updated/installed on all servers to make them equal. In this example, the results would be:

```
serverA has hadoop 1.0 but serverB does not have Hadoop installed
serverA has python 3.6 but serverB has python 3.5
testServerA is missing python.
testServerB has ruby but the other's do not (another way to put it would be serverA, serverB, and testServerA are missing ruby).
```

The data set above is essentially a print of this python code (currently hard-coding the server names for testing but would later be provided by choices from a UI):

```
    servers = ['serverA','serverB','testServerA','testServerB']
    installedSoftware = []
    for server in servers:
      installedSoftware.append('localhost/installed_software/?server=' + server).json())
    print(installedSoftware)
```

I've tried doing things like `print(set(installedSoftware[0]) - set(installedSoftware[1]))` but get an unhashable type dict.

I've also tried looping through the lists one by one to try to find the differences but feel like there should be a way to do this by sets that I'm just not getting.

Any advice on how to accomplish this? I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it has to be but I'm not very experienced with Python so I may be making a rookie mistake here.

Thanks for any help or advice that you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your use-case, perhaps you have access to a list of all the required software and their current latest versions.

```
expectedSw = OrderedDict([('hadoop', '1.0'), ('python', '3.6'), ('pip', '18.0'), 
('ruby', '2.5')])
currentInstallation = [] # Your data

for server in currentInstallation:
    for program in expectedSw.keys():
        if not any(sw.get('software', None) == program and
                   sw.get('version', None) == expectedSw[program] for sw in server):
            print '{} not installed or outdated on {}'.format(program, server[0]['server'])
```

If you don't have access to the list of programs and their latest versions, you could derive it from the installed software version data.

Side-note: [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) is quite handy for managing software installed on several machines

Comment: That's a good idea. I guess I could essentially take all of the software installed across all sites and then compare them across each site individually to see what's different. I'd likely need to store the "latest" version of the software too to compare against.

I'd love to use Puppet but, unfortunately, I have to work with the data from a DB (thus the API call) but I'll try your suggestion and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Happy to help :) Please consider marking this answer as the solution if it works for you